# Change from horizontal to vertical progress step-form bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am having a horizontal progress step-form. When I click on the buttons, the progress gets animated from left to right / right to left.
Now I want to achieve this vertically, that is along with the buttons, the progress bar should also be vertical and fill from top-to-bottom/bottom-to-top. Is there an easy way to achieve this without changing alot in my div containers?

That is I know I must change the #progress-bar-container, but how do I change the css rule?

```js
$(".step").click(function () {
            $(this).addClass("active").prevAll().addClass("active");
            $(this).nextAll().removeClass("active");
        });

        $(".step01").click(function () {
            $("#line-progress").css("width", "3%");
            $(".discovery").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        });

        $(".step02").click(function () {
            $("#line-progress").css("width", "25%");
            $(".strategy").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        });

        $(".step03").click(function () {
            $("#line-progress").css("width", "50%");
            $(".creative").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        });

        $(".step04").click(function () {
            $("#line-progress").css("width", "75%");
            $(".production").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        });

        $(".step05").click(function () {
            $("#line-progress").css("width", "100%");
            $(".analysis").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        });
```

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
        }


        h1 {
            color: #333;
            font-weight: 700;
            margin-top: 125px;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 4px;
            line-height: 23px;
        }

        /* --- Start progress bar --- */

        .process-wrapper {
            margin: auto;
            max-width: 1080px;
        }

        #progress-bar-container {
            position: relative;
            width: 90%;
            margin: auto;
            height: 100px;
            margin-top: 65px;
        }

        #progress-bar-container ul {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding-top: 15px;
            z-index: 9999;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: -40px
        }

        #progress-bar-container li:before {
            content: " ";
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: solid 2px #aaa;
            transition: all ease 0.3s;

        }

        #progress-bar-container li.active:before,
        #progress-bar-container li:hover:before {
            border: solid 2px #fff;

            background: linear-gradient(to right, #1a00aa 0%, rgb(0, 81, 255) 100%);
        }

        #progress-bar-container li {
            list-style: none;
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
            text-align: center;
            color: #aaa;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 11px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: 700;
            transition: all ease 0.2s;
            vertical-align: bottom;
            height: 60px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #progress-bar-container li .step-inner {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #progress-bar-container li.active,
        #progress-bar-container li:hover {
            color: #444;
        }

        #progress-bar-container li:after {
            content: " ";
            display: block;
            width: 6px;
            height: 6px;
            background: #777;
            margin: auto;
            border: solid 7px #fff;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-top: 40px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 13px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            transition: all ease 0.2s;

        }

        #progress-bar-container li:hover:after {
            background: #555;
        }

        #progress-bar-container li.active:after {
            background: #207893;
        }

        #progress-bar-container #line {
            width: 80%;
            margin: auto;
            background: #eee;
            height: 6px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 10%;
            top: 57px;
            z-index: 1;
            border-radius: 50px;
            transition: all ease 0.9s;
        }

        #progress-bar-container #line-progress {
            content: " ";
            width: 3%;
            height: 100%;
            background: #207893;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #207893 0%, #2ea3b7 100%);
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            border-radius: 50px;
            transition: all ease 0.9s;
        }

        #progress-content-section {
            width: 90%;
            margin: auto;
            background: #f3f3f3;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        #progress-content-section .section-content {
            padding: 30px 40px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #progress-content-section .section-content h2 {
            font-size: 17px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #333;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
        }

        #progress-content-section .section-content p {
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 1.8em;
            color: #777;
        }

        #progress-content-section .section-content {
            display: none;
            animation: FadeInUp 700ms ease 1;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            transform: translateY(15px);
            opacity: 0;
        }

        #progress-content-section .section-content.active {
            display: block;
        }

        @keyframes FadeInUp {
            0% {
                transform: translateY(15px);
                opacity: 0;
            }

            100% {
                transform: translateY(0px);
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="process-wrapper">
        <div id="progress-bar-container">
            <ul>
                <li class="step step01 active">
                    <div class="step-inner">A</div>
                </li>
                <li class="step step02">
                    <div class="step-inner">B</div>
                </li>
                <li class="step step03">
                    <div class="step-inner">C</div>
                </li>
                <li class="step step04">
                    <div class="step-inner">D</div>
                </li>
                <li class="step step05">
                    <div class="step-inner">E</div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div id="line">
                <div id="line-progress"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="progress-content-section">
            <div class="section-content discovery active">
                <h2>A</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum
                    ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in
                    dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor
                    mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas
                    volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit
                    orci.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="section-content strategy">
                <h2>B</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum
                    ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in
                    dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor
                    mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas
                    volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit
                    orci.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="section-content creative">
                <h2>C</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum
                    ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in
                    dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor
                    mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas
                    volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit
                    orci.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="section-content production">
                <h2>D</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum
                    ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in
                    dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor
                    mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas
                    volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit
                    orci.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="section-content analysis">
                <h2>E</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec neque justo, consequat non fermentum
                    ac, tempor eu turpis. Proin nulla eros, placerat non ipsum ut, dapibus ullamcorper ex. Nulla in
                    dapibus lorem. Suspendisse vitae velit ac ante consequat placerat ut sed eros. Nullam porttitor
                    mattis mi, id fringilla ex consequat eu. Praesent pulvinar tincidunt leo et condimentum. Maecenas
                    volutpat turpis at felis egestas malesuada. Phasellus sem odio, venenatis at ex a, lacinia suscipit
                    orci.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your html structure look ok but you need to work on your css rules if you want to change design

Comment: @The_Death_Raw Thank you, could you please help me out on how I should achieve this?

Comment: Try to do it and if your stuck, then come back to find help :)

Comment: @The_Death_Raw I know I have to change the #progress-bar-container, but I am finding it complicated to find out how. How do I add a new line to this?

Comment: Animate ```height``` (```.css('height',x)) instead of ```width```, but do try something yourself, you can't expect to post this and that someone solves this for you.

Comment: @prettyInPink thank you, I was more concerned about placing my buttons in vertical order one below the another. That is actually complicated for me.

Comment: As @The_Death_Raw mentioned, try setting it up and show the part you're stuck, this way people can provide assistance.

Comment: Okay I will do that, thank you